# s3 file upload fails in Lambda, succeeds with assumed role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is driving me nuts. I have a Lambda function. It has a policy attached to its service role (let's call it `lambda-func-service-role`) that allows uploading to a bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/sub/path/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to upload a file from within the lambda function I get the following error:

```
S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload /tmp/image_cropped.png to bucket/sub/path/view.png: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
Traceback
```

The code that does the upload is:

```
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        "s3"
    )
    s3_client.upload_file(filename, bucket, object_name)
```

... but ... if I set up a Jupyter notebook and assume the lambda function's role, I'm able to upload the file just fine:

```
client = boto3.client('sts',
                aws_access_key_id=...,
                aws_secret_access_key=...
            )
role = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/lambda-func-service-role',
    RoleSessionName='notebook'
)

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  aws_access_key_id=role['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                  aws_secret_access_key=role['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                  aws_session_token=role['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

s3.upload_file(filename, bucket, object_name)
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What do you have in the trust policy of `lambda-func-service-role`?

Comment: The trust policy for `lambda-func-service-role` just contains the user that use to assume the role in the Jupyter notebook. I print the caller identity in the lambda function and it is indeed `lambda-func-service-role`.

Comment: You need to allow the lambda function to assume that role in your trust policy.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but did you read my note above where I said I print the caller identity and it is indeed `lambda-func-service-role`? That means the lambda function has no trouble assuming the execution role. Also I didn't answer accurately above, `lambda.amazonaws.com` is also a trusted principal.

Comment: Yes, you did not mention that lambda is also a trusted principle in your policy, so I suspected that.

Comment: Can you please share the complete error trace, if that gives more details about the error?

Comment: Figured it out. It was due to the Lambda being in a VPC. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my lambda function was in a VPC.

I actually had a VPC endpoint to access S3 but the policy attached was for read only access. Adding a policy that included `PutObject` solved the problem:

```
    const s3BucketAccessPoint = vpc.addGatewayEndpoint("s3Endpoint", {
      service: ec2.GatewayVpcEndpointAwsService.S3,
    });

    s3BucketAccessPoint.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        actions: ["s3:PutObject*"],
        resources: ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/prefix/*"],
      })
    );
```